# SocketConnectException when connecting to GRPC Server

Tags: flutter, dart, heroku, grpc, grpc-node

I built a GRPC Server in NodeJS, Generated the Client Libraries for Dart and then Deployed the Server on Heroku.

When I tried connecting to the GRPC Server by Proividing the url as `https://api.appname.come` and provided the PORT Number From the Dart Client I keep Getting Failed to resolve host, SocketException.

This is the full Error message that I keep getting:

```
E/flutter (10136): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: gRPC Error (code: 14, codeName: UNAVAILABLE, message: Error connecting: SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'https://appname.herokuapp.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7), details: null, rawResponse: null)
E/flutter (10136):
```

Please, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Is there something in the error message?

Comment: I've edited the question and added the full error message. Thanks so much for your input

Comment: I think you don't need to specify https. Just use 'appname.herokuapp.com'